# Polynomial $P(x)=x^4+ax^3+2bx^2+cx-b+k$ with real roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

For which largest $k$ the polynomial $P(x)=x^4+ax^3+2bx^2+cx-b+k$ have real roots for arbitrary $a,b$ and $c$?

This is own problem. I can show that there are real roots for $k=-\frac{1}{4}$: $$P\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)+P\left(-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)=0.$$

Comment: Are you fixing $a, b,$ and $c$ and then choosing $k$? Or are you asking for a $k$ such that $P(x)$ has real roots for all $a, b, c$?

Comment: @Nick F: for all a,b,c.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that for $P(x)=x^4+0x^3+2bx^2+0x-b+k$,

- in case $b$ is positive, your $k$ can be as high as $b$, which grows ad infinitum for bigger and bigger values of $b$.
- in case $b$ is negative, your $k$ can be as high as $[b\times (b+1)]$, which grows ad infinitum for smaller and smaller values of $b$.